# ConnectionRefusedError at /password-reset/ [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, django, sendmail, smtpclient, smtplib

When user enter email for  password reset then error arise connection  failure which is related to server failure error .

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve the problem by setting an `EMAIL_BACKEND` in my `settings.py`.

If you just want to get things up and running, you can display emails in the console by putting this in your `settings.py`:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

More info in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/email/#email-backends

Comment: work for me as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want use smtp
set following code in settings.py:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

Comment: Sajad these lines of code  are include in the setting.py file despite that error is arise